# Event Handlers in ember.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to trigger an event from an Ember.js controller. I throws an error saying "ember.min.js:3 Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the action 'clicked'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.". Also I am not clear on how the event system works on itself for the targeted action. C  an someone help me with this. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Ember.js Application example</title>
      <!-- CDN's -->

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.10.0/ember.min.js"></script>
       <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.10.0-beta.3/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
       <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember.debug.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/2.4.3/ember.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container" id="github-app">

      </div>       
      <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Hello from Ember!</h1>
                {{outlet}}
            </div>
         </div>      
      </script>

      <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
      <p>This is a github explorer for all the users.</p>

      <ul>{{#each dev in controller}}
         <li><a href="#">{{dev}}</a></li>
         {{/each}}
      </ul>

      <p>
         <button class="btn btn-success" {{action "clicked"}}>Click Me</button>
      </p>

      <p>{{renderedOn}}</p>
      </script>      

      <script type="text/javascript">
      App = Ember.Application.create({
         rootElement:"#github-app"
      });
      App.IndexRoute=Ember.Route.extend({
         model:function(){
            return [
            "Sam",
            "Sandy",
            "Samudh"
            ];
         }
      });
      App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
         renderedOn : function(){
            return new Date();
         }.property(),
         actions    : {
            clickMe(){
               alert("I been clicked");
            }            
         }

      });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Also available at http://jsbin.com/cuxajiyuqa/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an action with the name 'clicked', and you tell your code to look for an action 'clicked' on clicking the button. Change

```
{{action "clicked"}}
```

into

```
{{action "clickMe"}}
```

or change the

```
clickMe(){
```

action into

```
clicked(){
```

and everything should be fine.

Check https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/templates/actions/ for the documentation on actions

Comment: Thank you so much, It fixed my issue. I am a new to ember.js and was following couple of videos online. And its the same that the author has followed. He hasn't used aliasis to the function as well. I wonder how it worked for him without making the above change, Anyways thanks for fixing this!